# Google maps API does not return postal code for "Chile" based addresses

Tags: google-maps, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

When I try to get the zipcode for an address using Google maps geocoding API, it works, the postal code is returned as part of the address_components array: (example: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=socoma%201%2C%20marrakesh).

But for Chile (the country) based addresses, it does not seem to return the postal code:(example: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=las%20condes%20santiago%20chile).

Any idea why would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a look at information about Las Condes area in wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Condes

and figured out that the postal code for Las Condes should be 7550000:

https://worldpostalcode.com/chile/region-metropolitana-de-santiago/santiago/las-condes

Now I try to search the postal code 7550000 in Chile using the components filtering which is the recommended way for postal code lookup

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A7550000%7Ccountry%3ACL&key=MY_API_KEY`

This request returns

```
{
    "results":[
    ],
    "status":"ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

So, at this point it looks like the postal code 7550000 is missing from the Google database and you are experiencing a data issue. In order to fix data issue you should report it to Google following the document:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088

Hopefully, Google will add the missing postal code soon.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough investigation, I'll report to Google and hopefully they can add fix.

Answer (score 0):

Google is not the answer for everything, Chile, and some other countries, has very precise postal codes.
Basically for cities, there is a postal code specific for each section of a street.
So for Las Condes, the general postal code is 7550000, but if you need the specific code for an address, you need to search on the [Chile post web site](https://www.correos.cl/codigo-postal)
eg Acapulco street, number 3700 give postal code 7550541.
You can also use postal databases like [GeoPostcodes](https://www.geopostcodes.com/)